# Accessing server on VMware Ubuntu from Windows via bridge networking

Tags: windows, ubuntu, server, vmware

I have installed a server on my Ubuntu VMware machine which is connected via bridge networking.

How can I connect to my server from Windows or from another pc operating Windows too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ubuntu server side :

- install ssh-server on the server (sudo apt-get install openssh-server)
- get the ip adress of your server (ifconfig).

On your Windows or another PC operating Windows side :

- Download and install [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) to connect via ssh to your server.